# I am using Datatable with vb.net and my dataset is about 20000 records. So how to do server side processing in vb.net

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am using Datatable with vb.net and my dataset contains around 20000 records. So how can I do server side processing in vb.net?

Here is some of my code I have come up with so far:

**jquery code:**

```
function dataTable() {
           var table = $('#tblMaterial').DataTable({
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">ifrtlp',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                "xls",
                "pdf"
            ],

            "sSwfPath": "assets/plugins/dataTables/tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        "order": [
            [2, "asc"]
        ],
        columnDefs: [{
            "searchable": false,
            "targets": 0
        }, {
            "searchable": false,
            "targets": 1
        }],
        aoColumnDefs: [{
            bSortable: false,
            aTargets: [0]
        }, {
            bSortable: false,
            aTargets: [1]
        }],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sServerMethod": 'POST',
        "sAjaxSource": "ServerSide.ashx",
        "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": 'json',
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback
            });

        }
    });

    $("#tblMaterial thead td").each(function(i) {
        if ((i == 0) || (i == 1)) {} else {
            var select = $('<select Class="form-control" style="padding-left: 0px;"><option value="">ALL</option></select>')
                .appendTo($(this).empty())
                .on('change', function() {
                    table.column(i)
                        .search($(this).val())
                        .draw();
                });

            table.column(i).data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
                select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
            });
        }
    });
};
```

**aspx table:**

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-tabletools dataTable" id="tblMaterial">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 3%;"></th>
            <th style="width: 3%;"></th>
            <th style="width: 15%;">Serial No.</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Material No.</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Pattern No.</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Drawing</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Work Order No.</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>


        <tr>
            <td style="width: 3%;"></td>
            <td style="width: 3%;"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>


        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

**vb.net code:**

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class serverside
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)
        ' Those parameters are sent by the plugin
        Dim iDisplayLength = Integer.Parse(context.Request("iDisplayLength"))
        Dim iDisplayStart = Integer.Parse(context.Request("iDisplayStart"))
        Dim iSortCol = Integer.Parse(context.Request("iSortCol_0"))
        Dim iSortDir = context.Request("sSortDir_0")

        ' Fetch the data from a repository (in my case in-memory)
        Dim strSql As String
        Dim sCon As New SQLConnect

        strSql = "select serialid," & _
                           " serialno," & _
                           " serialdesc," & _
                           " b.materialname," & _
                           " b.drawing," & _
                           " a.workorder," & _
                           " isnull((select top 1 patno from patternmaster where patid = a.patid),'Not Defined') as patno," & _
                           " case when a.activeflag = 1 then 'True' else 'False' end as activeflag" & _
                           " from serialmaster a," & _
                           " materialmaster b" & _
                           " where 1 = 1" & _
                           " and a.materialid = b.materialid" & _
                           " and b.activeflag = 1"

        sCon.sqlCmd.CommandText = strSql
        sCon.sqlAdp.SelectCommand = sCon.sqlCmd
        sCon.sqlAdp.Fill(sCon.DS, "Listing")

        Dim dtResult
        dtResult = sCon.DS.Tables("Listing").Copy


        ' Define an order function based on the iSortCol parameter
        Dim order As Func(Of Person, Object) = Function(p)
                                                   If iSortCol = 0 Then
                                                       Return p.serialid
                                                   End If
                                                   Return p.serialno

                                               End Function

        ' prepare an anonymous object for JSON serialization
        Dim result = New With { _
            Key .iTotalRecords = dtResult.Count(), _
            Key .iTotalDisplayRecords = dtResult.Count()
             }
        'Key .aaData = dtResult.Select(p New list () {p.Id.ToString(), p.Name}).Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength) _


        Dim serializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim json = serializer.Serialize(result)
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        context.Response.Write(json)

    End Sub
    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property



    Public Sub ProcessRequest1(context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Person
    Public Property serialid() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_serialid
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_serialid = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_serialid As Integer
    Public Property serialno() As String
        Get
            Return m_serialno
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_serialno = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_serialno As String
    Public Property serialdesc() As String
        Get
            Return m_serialdesc
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_serialdesc = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_serialdesc As String
    Public Property materialname() As String
        Get
            Return m_materialname
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_materialname = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_materialname As String
    Public Property drawing() As String
        Get
            Return m_drawing
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_drawing = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_drawing As String
    Public Property workorder() As String
        Get
            Return m_workorder
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_workorder = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_workorder As String
    Public Property patno() As String
        Get
            Return m_patno
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_patno = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_patno As String

    Public Property Id() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_Id
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_Id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Id As Integer
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Name As String


End Class
```

I had tried making vb.net code using C# code but keep getting invalid json response error and i had created aspx to get data on there, is any other way to get out of this problem?

Comment: You might want to clarify what you mean by making vb.net code using C#. Just a suggestion. :)

Comment: Actually I am getting ref code of C# from stackoverflow   but i am doing programming in vb.net. So i want to do it in vb.net

Comment: Then saying translating the vb.net code from the C# with a link to the original C# code would be more apt than making vb.net code using C# code. Just a tip to make your question easier to understand. :)

Comment: ok May you please provide solution

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have a table with lots of data and a jquery datatable instance. Do you have a vb.net app you are trying to do server-side processing with or asp.net app with vb.net your trying to handle ajax requests with or what? What's your actual problem and intended result?